# CodeMirror prohibit the entry of some characters

Tags: javascript, validation, codemirror

I'm trying to disable some characters in CodeMirror field to write, but i didn't found easy option in CodeMirror documentation, only CodeMirror Events:
https://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#events
I need to allow only [a-zA-Z0-9!()_&|] characters and forbid all others for input.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

CodeMirror has a set of keyboard events like  `"keydown"`, `"keypress"`, `"keyup"` that you can use to control input. For example, you can add the `"keydown"` event to your editor to prohibit entering of some characters:

```
editor.on("keydown", function (cm, event) {
  if (!event.key.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9!()_&|]/)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```